# Why do professional chess players point at the pieces with a middle finger?

Tags: analysis, learning, psychology, grandmaster

I've recently heard and then actually started to notice more and more that professional chess players tend to use a middle finger when pointing at pieces on the board like in this Anand vs Caruana game during the Sinquefield Cup 2017:

[image]
([source](https://twitter.com/LennartOotes/status/894341233958670336))

I am wondering, why is it happening?

<sub>Note: this is a genuine question, I am not trying to offend or make fun of anything or anyone here.</sub>

Comment: Simple: they are more comfortable using the middle finger.

Comment: How many of them actually do that? The question seems to imply that at least a few hundreds of them are doing that on a regular basis. Is this a fact?

Comment: @A.N.Other I don't have the exact stats :) But I am certain Kasparov does that as well. So, we have at least 3 players from very different schools of chess having the same habit.

Comment: Well, I always noticed that during analysis they tend to take the pieces (especially Knights) with the middle fingers, too. However it seems to me no more than a matter of personal taste or an habit that has developed among strong GMs. No "special reason" for doing so, IMHO.

Comment: Curiously enough i also had noticed that recently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When they're analyzing at a rapid pace, they tend to only need the thumb and index finger to pick up pieces and move them. Using the middle finger as well doesn't really help. So since that finger is freed up, they can use it to point (especially because pointing with the 4th finger or pinkie is awkward).

Or they subconsciously despise each other.

Answer (score 7):

Garry Kasparov has already answered this question. Unfortunately, it is a video and there is no text version.

You can find it on his official site: http://www.kasparov.com/garry-kasparov-answers-chess-questions-from-twitter-jan-16th-2018/

In the video, essentially, Kasparov said that he hasn't noticed it.

Comment: :) I like the fact that he says he never paid attention to that

Comment: Welcome on Chess.SE ! Since links tend to get broken over time, it is recommanded practice to sum up the relevant information from an external video in a few sentences in the answer itself. Can you explain what Kasparov's answer is ?

Comment: @Evargalo Sure, I will add what is on video tomorrow.

Comment: Kasparov said he hasn't noticed it, and that perhaps we should ask a psychologist.

Answer (score 4):

I think it very simple: if you point to something which is under your hand, it is much more convenient to use your middle finger. It seems a bit awkward, but more "natural" to your hand.

Comment: Also due to the middle finger normally being longer, it hides the piece less.

Answer (score 1):

I am no psychologist or a great chess player, but I do use common sense. When I move/remove chess pieces I use thumb and middle finger to do so as I few like the middle finger being the longest I believe it lessens the probability of accidentally knocking other pieces down...
With that finger being used in the game my brain makes it a primary pointer automatically...